# Pie Chart with connected google sheet

Tags: looker-studio

I have a 2 column table on one google sheet.

```
|user| count |
| a  | 1     |
| b  | 3     |
```

I connect the google sheet to a new google data studio project, and it creates 2 dimensions.
When I add a piechart, i cannot get the labels from column "user" to be shown, and it just shows the counts.

The google sheet contains multiple tabs that i will use like tables. Im using the created dimensions to populate the piechart.

Any help with this? Im very new to google datastudio.

Comment: It would be useful to see what is showing in an image and how the data is structured. Is user defined as a text dimension and count as a number? Is it showing the right proportions? Have you looked in the style section to see what the data labels are showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pie chart select `user` as dimension and `count` as metric in the `DATA` panel:

[image]

You can then, in the `STYLE` tab, change the `labels` to `label` instead of `value`:

[image]

Or, if you want to keep the count, just leave `value` as `labels` and add a `legend`:

[image]